# Android Music service in background

Tags: android, android-activity, service, background-music

I have a problem here, I have a music track works in the background of an app that is never stop and when  I add OnDestroy() or Pause() in my main activity class gives me an error when running the application not in the class and I don't know where to put them to control the music in the main !!

here are the codes that gives me an error:

```
mServ.pauseMusic();  
mServ.resumeMusic();
mServ.stopMusic();
```

The Main Activity:

```
private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicService mServ;

private ServiceConnection Scon = new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder  binder) {
            mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder)binder).getService();
            }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServ = null;
    }

    };
    void doBindService(){
        bindService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class),
                Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService()
    {
        if(mIsBound)
        {
            unbindService(Scon);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent music = new Intent();
    music.setClass(this,MusicService.class);
    startService(music);
```

And The Service Activity:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private int length = 0;

public MusicService(){}

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MusicService getService()
 {
    return MusicService.this;
 }
```

}

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.la);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    if(mPlayer != null){

        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
    }

    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }

    });
}

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent , int flags, int startId)
{
     mPlayer.start();
     return START_STICKY;
}

public void pauseMusic()
{
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mPlayer.pause();
        length=mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Music is Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void resumeMusic()
{
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()==false)
    {
        mPlayer.seekTo(length);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Music is started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}

public void stopMusic()
{
    mPlayer.stop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Music is stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy ()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mPlayer != null)
    {
    try{
     mPlayer.stop();
     mPlayer.release();
        }finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, "Music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(mPlayer != null)
    {
        try{
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
        }finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }



    }

    return false;

}
```

}

The code is based on this link [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App)

Comment: Describe "gives me an error": what error? any name? any stacktrace?

Comment: I don't know where to put in the main.. when i put it in OnCreate() Bundle in the main it did not run and when i put it anywhere else outside OnCreate() it seems it didn't found the object of the service class

Comment: You must provide better information than this. If you did something wrong, show us the stacktrace. If your code seems good but the music is not playing, post your code.

Comment: Could U please help me i have put the main code and the service code